# How to String.match() distinct it ${SOME_TEXT} using Regex

Tags: javascript, regex, string, string-matching

I need this string:

```
var x = 'Hi ${name}! How are you? ${name}, you are old! ${name} share with ${other} how do u ${feel}!'
```

I need to know using Regex how much distinct ${ANY_THING} exists. In example above i expect 3: ${name}, ${other}, ${feel}

I'm trying it:

```
x.match(\${([a-zA-Z]))
```

But the output is wrong :(

Thanks!

Comment: First one should be ${name} instead of {$name}?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I will fix it.

Comment: This is a great question but I feel as if the title could be more relevant - as it is, it's not likely to show up in any search results for folks having similar problems.

Comment: Edited: How to String.match() distinct it ${SOME_TEXT} using Regex. Better now? :) I'm opened to suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find this solution at #regex IRC Channel by *farn* user:

```
x.match(/\$\{([^\}]+)\}(?![\S\s]*\$\{\1\})/g);
```

output:

```
['${name}',
 '${other}',
 '${feel}']
```

and

```
x.match(/\$\{([^\}]+)\}(?![\S\s]*\$\{\1\})/g).length;
```

output:

```
3
```

:)

Comment: `x.match(/\$\{([^\}]+)\}(?![\S\s]*\$\{\1\})/g).replace();` outputs `TypeError: Object [object Array] has no method 'replace'`

Comment: @zerkms may there's a problem in how do you use it. To prove that it's complete ok, look at his link: http://regex101.com/r/eW3jY4 Cheers!

Comment: it's not me using it - I just took the code you provided in your answer exactly as it is

Comment: There's some problem with your code. Look: http://jsbin.com/luheq/1/edit?js,console

Comment: zerkms, sorry. I guessed that you were saying that the problem was with regex, not with replace(). I fix it after. Sorry again. You don't need act as if people were always making jokes or kidding with you. people make mistakes, you may be too perfect.

Answer (score 5):

> I need to know using Regex how much distinct ${ANY_THING} exists

```
x.match(/\$\{[^\}]+\}/g)
 .sort()
 .filter(function(element, index, array) {
     return index == array.indexOf(element);
 }) // this .filter() filters out the duplicates (since JS lacks of built in
    // unique filtering functions
 .length;
```

The code above would return `3`, as that's how many distinct items are in the `x` string.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cae6P/

PS: It's not possible to do it with regular expression only. You need to filter duplicates using the `.filter()` solution or some other similar

Comment: Yes, its solve the problem but i test it at node console :) and its appear that if just using the regex, it's matching ${name} 3x times:

> x.match(/\$\{[^\}]+\}/g);
[ '${name}',
  '${name}',
  '${name}',
  '${other}',
  '${feel}' ]

Comment: @user3207109: yes, it matches name 3 times since there are 3 name elements. So?

Comment: Its possible that using just regex and x.match() just match ${name} (1 time), ${other}, ${feel} not ${name}, ${name}, ${name} (3 times), ${other}, ${feel}?

Comment: @CodeWarrior: I hardly doubt

Comment: look what i found: x.match(/\$\{([^\}]+)\}(?![\S\s]*\$\{\1\})/g); Cool man!

Answer (score 0):

To match the syntax you want you need this:

```
x.match(/\$\{([a-zA-Z]+)\}/)
```

Comment: If you need the whole `${name}` instead of `name` just do `x.match(/(\$\{[a-zA-Z]+\})/)`.

Comment: Thanks, but the question that really and correct answer the question came from zerkms :) Cheers!