# Regex global replace not replacing first occurrence

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to make a quick and dirty template test, but when the regular expression replaces, it only replaces the last occurrence, I thought that the `\g` would replace all copies. but it's only matching the last occurrence.

([How to String.match() distinct it ${SOME_TEXT} using Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21292764/how-to-string-match-distinct-it-some-text-using-regex))

**What I'm trying to do is prompt the user once for each unique variable name.**

```
Title = t
name = n
result = '${Title} - n - t'
```

Using `/\$\{([^\}]+)\}/g` works, but prompts the user multiple times.

```
Title = t
name = n
Title = t
result = 't - n - t'
```

So how can I replace each token with a single value no matter how many times it appears.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="application/javascript">

        window.copyToClipboard = function(n) {
            var u = "_hiddenCopyText_", t, i, r;
            t = document.getElementById(u);
            t.textContent = n;
            i = document.activeElement;
            t.focus();
            t.setSelectionRange(0, t.value.length);
            try {
                r = document.execCommand("copy")
            } catch (f) {
                r = !1
            }
            return i && typeof i.focus == "function" && i.focus(),
                t.textContent = "",
                r
        };
        //${varname}
        window.templateRegex = /\$\{([^\}]+)\}(?![\S\s]*\$\{\1\})/g;
        window.test = " ${Title} - ${Name} - ${Title}"
        window.copyTemplate = function (template) {
            var result = template.replace(window.templateRegex, function(match, token){
               return window.prompt("replace value for ${"+token+"}","${"+token+"}");
            });
            window.copyToClipboard(result);
        };

    </script>
</head>
<textarea id="_hiddenCopyText_"></textarea>
<button onclick="copyTemplate(window.test)">Test</button>
</html>
```

**JsFiddle** https://jsfiddle.net/ksu37c3b/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If same `${..}`(${Title}) occurs several times, `/\$\{([^\}]+)\}(?![\S\s]*\$\{\1\})/g` will only match the last one. To match all the elements, `/\$\{([^\}]+)\}/g` will work, it doesn't need the negative lookahead `(?![\S\s]*\$\{\1\})`.
In the string `"${Title} - ${Name} - ${Title}"`, only `${Name}` and `${Title}` matches the pattern, because the first one and the last one are the same, if you change the string, for example, `"${Title2} - ${Name} - ${Title}"` it will match all the element, because ${Title2} and ${Title} are not equal. That's what the `(?![\S\s]*\$\{\1\})` try to do, if the last `${..}` and the current `${..}` are the same, it won't match.

## update

> So how can I replace each token with a single value no matter how many times it appears.

You can use the `match()` method to get an array of tokens occured, then replace it one by one, the code below will work:

```js
window.templateRegex = /\$\{([^\}]+)\}(?![\S\s]*\$\{\1\})/g;
window.test = " ${Title} - ${Name} - ${Title}";
var userinput, reg, i;
var arr = window.test.match(/\$\{([^\}]+)\}(?![\S\s]*\$\{\1\})/g);
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    arr[i] = arr[i].replace(/[\$\{\}]/g, "");
    userinput = window.prompt("replace value for " + arr[i]);
    reg = new RegExp("\\$\\{" + arr[i] + "\\}", 'g');
    console.log(reg);
    window.test = window.test.replace(reg, userinput);
}
alert(window.test);
```

I have modified your code as follows:

```js
window.copyToClipboard = function(n) {
  var u = "_hiddenCopyText_",
    t, i, r;
  t = document.getElementById(u);
  t.textContent = n;
  //** snip **//
};
//${varname}
window.templateRegex = /\$\{([^\}]+)\}(?![\S\s]*\$\{\1\})/g;
window.test = " ${Title} - ${Name} - ${Title}";
window.copyTemplate = function(template) {
    var result = template;
    var userinput, reg;
    var arr = result.match(/\$\{([^\}]+)\}(?![\S\s]*\$\{\1\})/g);
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        arr[i] = arr[i].replace(/[\$\{\}]/g, "");
        userinput = window.prompt("replace value for " + arr[i]);
        reg = new RegExp("\\$\\{" + arr[i] + "\\}", 'g');
        console.log(reg);
        result = result.replace(reg, userinput);
    }
    window.copyToClipboard(result);
};
```

```html
<textarea id="_hiddenCopyText_"></textarea>
<button onclick="copyTemplate(window.test)">Test</button>​
```

Comment: That prompts 3 times, not twice.

Comment: @Ryan The Leach  I updated my answer, the code above prompts 2 times.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want `/\$\{([^\}]+)\}(?![\S\s]\$\{\1\})/`

I just removed the * in the middle of the negative look ahead because it was causing it to match the final occurrence every time.

Comment: Doing that ends up with the result "T - ${Name} - ${Title}"

Comment: I must have copied it wrong. Removing the star makes 3 prompts, one for title, one for name, one for title. What I'm trying to do is have a single prompt for title, and a single prompt for name.

Comment: Why don't you just take what's returned, look at the array of matched results and check if anything has been duplicated? Then you can just prompt for matches that haven't been prompted for already.

If you can't figure it out in the next 3 hours, I'll take a deeper look into it since I finish work in 3 hours time.

Comment: I've worked it out by storing the values in an object without using regex, I was fairly curious if regex was able to do multiple replacements.

Comment: It's not very clear what you're trying to achieve. I literally have no clue what you mean.