# Slight trouble with table row fetch script

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm kinda new to scripting and all and just wanted to know if anyone could help me edit my code to hide the whole table from the start and then just display the rows that match the keyword.

Right now what the code does is:
You enter a keyword in an inputbox
The script searches through a table looking for rows matching the keyword.
Hide all other rows.

But i would like it to work another way, but don't really know how to.
What i would like it to do is:
Display the inputbox only on the page.(Table is hidden)
Display the results that match the keyword without displaying the whole table.

Code:

```
 var TableSearch = function(searchBoxId, dataTableId, options) {
    this.searchBox = document.querySelector('#' + searchBoxId);
    this.dataTable = document.querySelector('#' + dataTableId);
    this.options = options;
}

TableSearch.prototype = {

    init: function(searchBoxId, dataTableId, options) {
        // defaults options
        var settings = {
            firstRowHeader: true, 
            highlightCss: "style='background-color:yellow'",
            noResultsText: null
        };

        if (this.options) {
            for (var key in settings) {
                // Update settings if valid option and value was supplied.
                if (this.options.hasOwnProperty(key) && (this.options[key] != null && this.options[key].toString() != '')) {
                    if (key == 'highlightCss') {
                        settings[key] = "class='" + this.options[key] + "'";
                        continue;
                    }
                    settings[key] = this.options[key];
                }
            }
        }

        this.options = settings;
        this.searchBox.addEventListener('keyup', this.search.bind(this), false);
    },

    search: function(e) {
        if(e.keyCode == 27) {
            this.searchBox.value = ''; // Clear search on Esc
        }

        this.toggleNoResult('remove');

        var keyword =  this.escapeSpecialChars(this.searchBox.value);
        var textSearchRegex = new RegExp(keyword, "ig"); // case in-sensitive
        var rowDisplay, rowObj, rowHtml, match; 
        var firstRowIndex = (this.options.firstRowHeader == true) ? 1 : 0;

        for (var rowIndex = firstRowIndex; rowIndex < this.dataTable.rows.length; rowIndex++) {
            rowDisplay = '';
            rowObj = this.dataTable.rows.item(rowIndex);
            rowHtml = rowObj.innerHTML.replace(/<mark[^/>]*>/g,'').replace(/<\/mark>/g,''); // remove previous highlighting

            if (keyword == '')
                rowDisplay = 'table-row';
            else {
                match = rowHtml.replace(/<[^>]*>/g, '').match(textSearchRegex); // strip html tags and search for keyword
                if(match) {
                    // Get unique matches: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21292834/1440057
                    match = match.sort().filter(function(element, index, array) { return index == array.indexOf(element); });
                    var tempHtml = rowHtml;
                    for (var i = 0; i < match.length; i++)
                        tempHtml = this.highlight(tempHtml, match[i]);

                    if (tempHtml.search(/<\/mark>/g) > -1) {
                        rowHtml = tempHtml;
                        rowDisplay = 'table-row';
                    }
                    else // Keyword did not match with any column content
                        rowDisplay = 'none';
                }
                else // Keyword did not match even in the row text content
                    rowDisplay = 'none';
            }

            rowObj.innerHTML = rowHtml;
            rowObj.style.display = rowDisplay;
        }

        // Check if 'no results' row needs to be added
        if (keyword != '' && this.options.noResultsText && this.dataTable.innerHTML.search(/style=\"display: table-row;\"/g) == -1)
            this.toggleNoResult('add');
    },

    highlight: function(rowHtml, match) {
        var row = document.createElement('tr');
        row.innerHTML = rowHtml;

        var textReplaceRegex = new RegExp(this.escapeSpecialChars(match), "g"); // case sensitive
        var highlightMarkup = '<mark ' + this.options.highlightCss + '>' + match + '</mark>';
        var cell = null;
        var htmlOut = '';

        for (var i = 0; i < row.cells.length; i++) {
            cell = row.cells.item(i);
            // Highlighting works only for direct text content, not nested tags.
            // e.g. searching "blog" in <td><a href="url">my blog</a></td> won't work.
            if (cell.children.length == 0) {
                if (cell.textContent.indexOf(match) > -1) {
                    // Match found in this cell, highlight it
                    htmlOut += '<td>' + cell.textContent.replace(textReplaceRegex, highlightMarkup) + '</td>';
                    continue;
                }
            }
            htmlOut += '<td>' + cell.innerHTML + '</td>';
        }

        return htmlOut;
    },

    escapeSpecialChars: function(inStr) {
        return inStr.replace(/[\-\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|]/g, "\\$&");
    },

    toggleNoResult: function(mode) {
        var noResultsRow;
        if (mode == 'add') {
            noResultsRow = this.dataTable.insertRow(this.dataTable.rows.length);
            noResultsRow.setAttribute('id', 'noResultsRow');
            var noResultsRowCell = noResultsRow.insertCell(0);
            noResultsRowCell.setAttribute('colspan', this.dataTable.rows[0].cells.length);
            noResultsRowCell.setAttribute('align', 'center');
            noResultsRowCell.textContent = this.options.noResultsText;
        }
        else if (mode == 'remove') {
            noResultsRow = this.dataTable.querySelector('#noResultsRow');
            if (noResultsRow != null) {
                this.dataTable.deleteRow(this.dataTable.rows.length - 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Can you post a full working example including html in a stack snippet or jsfiddle?

Comment: http://jelon51.pl/hjdkashdjkashdkjasd.html here's a cut down version of the site, couldn't get it to work in fiddle